# reduce the width of a div 1% every 100th of a second with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use javascript to reduce the `width` of a `<div>` from 100% to 1% over the course of 10 seconds but I'm a bit of a learner driver with javascript and jquery so I'm having a bit of a problem.

My code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="timer"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var i = 100;
while(i>1) {
    var currentWidth = $(".timer").css(width);
    currentWidth = currentWidth-1;
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $(".timer").width(currentWidth+'%')
    }, 100);
    i--;
}
```

But it ain't working. I've cobbled it together myself from different places so it could be completely wrong. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: BTW your question title suggests it should shrink 100 times per second.

Comment: You're doing pretty well. Your problem lies in the fact that your call to width() returns a percentage, which is not a number and therefore you can't subtract from it. Look at parseInt().

Comment: Also, setInterval will call the function automatically every tenth of a second right now - but you are setting 100 intervals because you are doing it in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the width as an inline style...

```
<div class="timer" style="width:100%"></div>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
var shrinkit = setInterval(function()
               {
                   //you can access the width as a percentage pretty easily:
                   var width = parseInt($('.timer')[0].style.width)-1;
                   $(".timer").width(width + '%');
               }, 100);
setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(shrinkit); }, 10100);
```

And I'm just clearing the interval a little after 10 seconds instead of counting, seems more intuitive to me in this case.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/4SeP9/

Comment: Thanks for this. It's funny how it looks dead obvious when you see it actually working :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't return widths as a percentage so you'll have to go manually

```
var width = 100;
function shrinkMyDiv(){
    width--;
    if(width > 0){
        $(".timer").css('width', width + '%');
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalTimer);
    }
}

// Start an interval timer which runs every 10 milliseconds (1 hundredth of a second)
var intervalTimer = setInterval(shrinkMyDiv(), 10);
```